# Converting Large .wav files to .txt files using MsAzure Quick Start sample codes [Continuous Recognition]

Tags: python-3.x, azure, speech-to-text

As suggested in the Stack Overflow I have tried converting a large .wav file into an accurate .txt file by using the sample codes in the Quick Start of MsAzure Speech to text option. It is giving me error.

The Code I wrote are

```
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename="FilePath//Audio.wav")
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

done = False

def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    nonlocal done
    done = True

(Here I got an error 
File "<ipython-input-10-1ca5a9053d2a>", line 5
    nonlocal done
    ^
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'done' found


speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))

speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

import time
speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
while not done:
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Can anybody suggest me any correction to where I got wrong? Also I would appreciate if any body can suggest any different method on the MsAzure to convert large .wav files to .txt.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` to resolve your issue.

```
done = False

def stop_cb(evt):
    print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    global done
    done = True
```

The `nonlocal` keyword is used to work with variables inside nested functions, where the variable should not belong to the inner function.

In your case you don't have outer function / nested functions. So you will have to make use of the `global` keyword.

Correct usage of nonlocal would be as below :

```
def myfunc1():
  x= "test string"
  def myfunc2():
    nonlocal x
    x = "test string updated"
```

**Explanation :**

Here **myfunc1** and **myfunc2** are nested. So you could use `nonlocal x` refer to the variable `x` of outer scope  function **myfunc1**

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work